# Why does my Perl CGI complain "Can't locate Mysql.pm"?

Tags: mysql, perl, cgi

I have two folders `php` and `perl`. They contain `index.php` and `index.pl`, respectively.

My Perl code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Mysql;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; 
print "<h2>PERL-mySQL Connect</h2>";
print "page info";
$host = "localhost";
$database = "cdcol";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = Mysql->connect($host, $database, $user, $password);
$db->selectdb($database);
```

When i run above code (by typing `http://localhost:88/perl/` in the browser), I get the following error:

`Can't locate Mysql.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/xampp/perl/site/lib/ C:/xampp/perl/lib C:/xampp/perl/site/lib C:/xampp/apache) at C:/xampp/htdocs/perl/index.pl line 2. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/xampp/htdocs/perl/index.pl line 2.`

whereas browsing to `http://localhost:88/php/` works.

`index.php` has:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if($con)
    {
        if(mysql_select_db("cdcol", $con))
        {
            $sql="SELECT Id From products";
            if(mysql_query($sql))
            {
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                if ($result) ...
```

Comment: For the record, you do not have connection problems. You just don't have the perl Mysql module installed within the (xampp) path.

Comment: as extraneon says, you need to make certain that perl is configured correctly for the user under which the web-server is running.

Comment: @dexter My earlier point stands: There is no need to learn to program like it is 1999. Use `DBI`. Also, you **must** use `strict` and `warnings`.

Comment: Don't use 15-years old Perl tutorials

Comment: Sinan Ünür: In 1999, DBi and "use strict: were already standard, so this code is from even earlier times.

Comment: @all:sorry for the old code.. im a new to this perl thing ..trying to learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI) in conjunction with [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBD::mysql).

You should use a standard CGI processing module such as [CGI::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI::Simple).

```
use strict; use warnings;
use CGI::Simple;
use DBI;

my $cgi = CGI::Simple->new;
my $dsn = sprintf(
    'DBI:mysql:database=%s;host=%s',
    'cdcol', 'localhost'
);

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, root => '',
    { AutoCommit => 0, RaiseError => 0 }
);

my $status = $dbh ? 'Connected' : 'Failed to connect';

print $cgi->header, <<HTML;
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Perl CGI Script</h1>
<p>$status</p>
</body>
</html>
HTML
```

Comment: above code gave me following error:   The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
Can't locate CGI/Simple.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/xampp/perl/site/lib/ C:/xampp/perl/lib C:/xampp/perl/site/lib C:/xampp/apache) at C:/xampp/htdocs/perl/index.pl line 4. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/xampp/htdocs/perl/index.pl line 4. ,